# how do i parse MQTT from string to float in c# / unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mqtt

im trying to develop an mqtt string for my unity project using m2mqttunity to subscribe and receive message from publisher. 
i have successfully subscribe and received message and the log.
the problem is, i cant seems to find a way to parse the payload string message to float so i can use the float as a temperature input for my unity demo. 
the error i got is :

```html
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) [0x00057] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00013] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00007] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at mqttTest.client_MqttMsgPublishReceived (System.Object sender, uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e) [0x00021] in C:\Users\Tila\Unity3d_MQTT-master\Assets\MQTT\scripts\test\mqttTest.cs:38 
  at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.OnMqttMsgPublishReceived (uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgPublish publish) [0x0000f] in C:\Users\Tila\Unity3d_MQTT-master\Assets\MQTT\scripts\MqttClient.cs:764 
  at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.ReceiveEventThread () [0x000f8] in C:\Users\Tila\Unity3d_MQTT-master\Assets\MQTT\scripts\MqttClient.cs:1487 
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) [0x00014] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0002b] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0  occurred
```

and the GIT is

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Utility;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions;

using System;

public class mqttTest : MonoBehaviour {
 private MqttClient client;
 public int tempDemo;
 
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  
  // create client instance 
  client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),1883, false , null ); 
  
  // register to message received 
  client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived; 
  
  string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
  client.Connect(clientId); 
  
  // subscribe to the topic "/home/temperature" with QoS 2 
  client.Subscribe(new string[] { "hello/world" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

  


 }
 void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e) 
 { 

  Debug.Log("Received: " + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message)  );
  tempDemo = int.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));

 } 

 void OnGUI(){
  if ( GUI.Button (new Rect (20,40,80,20), "Level 1")) {
   Debug.Log("sending...");
   client.Publish("hello/world", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bro"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, true);
   Debug.Log("sent");
  }
 }


 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {



 }
}
```

Comment: an int isn't a float. Try float.Parse instead of int.Parse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Your client_MqttMsgPublishReceived method has `tempDemo = int.Parse(...)`

but you've suggested that the incoming data is a float. `int.Parse` won't parse floats and doubles, for that you need [float.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=netcore-3.1) or [double.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netcore-3.1). You can always cast (truncate) the non-integer number to an int.

Possible fix:

```
tempDemo = (int)double.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
```

Comment: you have just saved me from not progressing my final bachelor assignment thanks a lot!. the real works starts now where i need to make a dynamic modelling :(

Comment: Happy to help and best of luck with your degree! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)